# Write binary numpy array of zeros and ones to file using cv2 or Pillow

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, opencv, python

Is it possible to write binary numpy array containing 0 and 1 to file using opencv (cv2) or Pillow? I was using scipy.misc.imsave and it worked well, but i read it's depreciated so i wanted to switch to other modules, but when trying to write such an array i see only black image. I need to have 0/1 values, and not 0/255 for further processing.

Comment: Please show minimum code to write the file and minimum code to read the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are writing pixels with values `(0, 0, 0)` or `(1, 1, 1)` to the image you are seeing an image that is entirely black and almost-black, so it looks black.

You can multiply your array by 255 to get an array of `{ (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255) }` which would be black and white. When you read the image you can convert back to 0s and 1s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, I wasn't aware that when writing array of 0 and 1 to png file using scipy.misc.imsave ones are converted to 255 and that's why i could see white objects.